# how to delete data in disconnected architecture?

Tags: ado.net

**How delete data in disconnected architecture using query.**
*I tried but nothing happens.*

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Vova\\Desktop\\fenix.accdb";
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ZZZ";
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "ZZZ");

        string del = "delete from ZZZ where m_id=253";


        OleDbCommand delete = new OleDbCommand(del, command.Connection);



        adapter.DeleteCommand = delete;

        adapter.Update(dataset, "ZZZ");
```

*After update nothing happens, record still in the database.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to [`Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) a `DataRow` in the `DataTable`, then the `DeleteCommand` is triggered for this row when you call `adapter.Update(dataset, "ZZZ");`.

For example:

```
DataRow rowToDelete = dataset.Tables["ZZZ"].AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Field<int>("m_id") == 253);
if(rowToDelete != null)
    rowToDelete.Delete();
adapter.Update(dataset, "ZZZ");
```

You don't need to call `Update` after every change/delete action. You can call it at the end, then the appropriate command is triggered for every changed row.

`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` is a LINQ method, so you need to add `using System.Linq;`.

---

If you don't want to use the `DataAdapter` or `DataRow.Delete` then you can achieve the same with the `OleDbCommand` only:

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Vova\\Desktop\\fenix.accdb"))
using(var delete = new OleDbCommand("delete from ZZZ where m_id=253", connection ))
{
    connection.Open();
    int deleted = delete.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: ty for answer, but it is possible delete using "del = "delete from ZZZ where m_id=253";" without LINQ method.

Comment: @Vadim: yes, but then you don't need a `DataSet` or a `DataAdapter` at all. You can use a single `OleDbCommand` with this sql. Then i don't understand the "disconnected" part of your question. Edited my answer.